# Fixable? Or decor?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, repair

Is it possible to repair this guitar or just a waste of time. Either way I'm going to try. Just wanted opinion from somewhere else.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: *Decor as in a decoration for around the house. Some people take old guitars and hang them on the wall or stick them in the corner just for the vibe.

Comment: Yes. It can be repaired. Whether or not it is worth it is up to you.

Comment: I can't read the maker - does it actually have any extrinsic value if rebuilt, or would it make more sense to hang a junk-shop relic on the wall instead? Could probably get one for less than the price of new machine heads.

Answer (score 1):

At worst, if an attempt to repair fails, it can still hang on the wall. A good two-pack epoxy adhesive and some carefully placed clamps will sort out the parting of the ways, but not sure about the electrics side. Without the pup and the circuit, it'll end up as a poor acoustic, and won't even be convincing hiding the damp patch on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

With a blown out truss rod and a shattered neck heel, I'd say you are going to have difficulty making it playable again. It would be good for practicing your gluing and clamping though. You could cut open or take off the face and put in some shelves for a nice curio display.